# Count total number of multiple line items in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. Not sure how to Google it though for info to get started.

I have a table called "Questions_Asked". It has a list of all the questions asked about an item. So my data looks like this:

```
id  asker_id    item_in_question_id created_at  updated_at 
115199   NULL                  NULL         1/31/13 21:43   1/31/13 21:43 
23487    18189                 2870         10/25/11 18:25  10/25/11 18:25 
24400    21386                 2900         11/9/11 16:09   11/9/11 16:09 
24870    25243                 2900         11/15/11 14:43  11/15/11 14:43
```

Basically I need a count of all the items with multiple questions. So in this case, item 2900 has 2 questions asked.

I know this probably involves a sub-query and grouping, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it being brand new to it.

I should also add that I need to be able to pull this based on a vague criteria. So while I can pull it if I specifically run the query for, "WHERE item_in_question_id = 2900;", I need to be able to run a query where the created_at falls between a certain range and then I can just do a "SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, COUNT xxxx AS Askers" etc.

Comment: you should be able to just do a COUNT() of the rows and GROUP BY item (i.e 2900)

Comment: can you clarify what date range you want the query to pull from?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I think that works. Maybe I've just been overthinking it. For some reason I thought you couldn't select something unless it was also in the group by declaration, which I didn't know how to get around because I didn't want to group by the asker_id. Thanks.

Comment: you don't want to group by the item_in_question_id? why not?

Comment: @JohnRuddell sorry, I meant the asker_id. I wanted a table with all the asker_ids and then the corresponding amounts of aggregate item_in_question_ids.

Comment: ah gotcha. yea you should want to group by the item :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work.

```
SELECT 
    qa.id, 
    qa.created_at, 
    qa.updated_at, 
    COUNT(qa.id) AS Askers
FROM Questions_Asked as qa
WHERE qa.created_at BETWEEN your_first_date AND your_second_date
GROUP BY qa.item_in_question_id
```

Comment: this query will not return all of the asker id's though (because they are grouped into one row if theres more than one per item).. if you want that then I can see what I can do.

Comment: Not sure if you saw my last comment, but ignore it. Works great, thanks again for your help.